# Bootstrap 4 : How to make the item of list-group active when clicking it via jquery or vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Bootstrap 4 : How to make the item of list-group active when clicking it via jquery or vuejs?

this is the component:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/list-group/#linked-items

the first item is active,but clicking another one will not make it active,how to do it via jquery or vuejs? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script>
// es6 js
new Vue({
  el: '#listGroup',
  data {
    selected: 0
  }, 
  methods: {
    isSelected (i) {
      return i === this.selected
    }
  }
})
</script>

<div class="list-group" id='listGroup'>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : isSelected(0) }" v-on:click="selected = 0">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : isSelected(1) }"  v-on:click="selected = 1">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : isSelected(2) }"  v-on:click="selected = 2">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : isSelected(3) }"  v-on:click="selected = 3">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : isSelected(4) }"  v-on:click="selected = 4">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

This defines a property of selected. When clicking a list item, the v-on hook changes the value of selected to the integer id in the v-on attributes expression. As the value of this.selected changes within the vue, the classes change because they are bound the output of the method isSelected() which is called when the selected value changes.

http://codepen.io/tremendusapps/pen/bebGGj

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mg0xa1ku/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.list-group > a').click(function(e){
  // find/remove all active classes from each a
  $('.list-group > a').removeClass('active');

  // add active selected a
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**Specific class to the menu**

I would add 'mainNav' class so I can target it. Just in case I have two 'list-group' on the same page

```
<div class="list-group mainNav">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>


$('.mainNav > a').click(function(e){
  // find/remove all active classes from each a
  $('.mainNav > a').removeClass('active');

  // add active selected a
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your list-group div an id and select them active list group item with `$('#name .list-group-item active')`.

Comment: Oh no. This is a 'jquery' way to do things. You don't need to do that with dynamic data binding libraries like VueJS. In the jquery world, you tend to - or sometimes have to - look at the DOM to store data, read status (like active). Better to think the other way around and have the data bound to the DOM, so that when the data changes, the DOM auto updates. Everything you need in VueJS is there, question of reading the manual but the section you're looking for is here: http://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html